# Eclipse: Hot Code Replace when saving

Tags: eclipse

Often in Eclipse when I hit Cmd S (to save my file) with a running app I get this dialog box appearing:

[image]

How do I disable it from appearing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number of options:

- Tick the checkbox and hit 'Continue'
- Disable automatic building of your projects: deselect Project > Build Automatically
- Change Window > Preferences > Java > Debug - Hot Code Replace
- Do yourself a big favor and use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) (I'm not associated with them in any way other than being a very happy customer)